# C++ - Is my template function failing because of bad predicate design?

Tags: c++, iterator, predicate

I'm trying to implement a function which finds the maximum value of any given array, vector or set in C++ called find_max for my school assignment. Using the function looks like this (pred_int is the predicate):

```
int arr_int[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 9, 2, 0 };
int main(){
  const int* maxint = find_max( &arr_int[0],
    &arr_int[sizeof(arr_int)/sizeof(*arr_int)], pred_int);
  std::cout <<*maxint <<"\n";
}
```

However, my code doesn't work with vectors or sets from std (it works for arrays like in the example). The errors are along the lines of "cannot convert argument 2 from 'Iterator' to 'const void *'". This is how I built my function with the predicates required for the test values:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Predicate>
Iterator find_max(
    Iterator cur, Iterator last, Predicate pred) {
    Iterator max = cur;
    while (cur != last) {
        if (pred(max, cur) < 0) max = cur;
        cur++;
    }
    return max;
}

int pred_int(const void* p1, const void* p2) {
    int first = *((int*)p1);
    int second = *((int*)p2);
    return first - second;
}

int pred_char(const void* p1, const void* p2) {
    char* first = (char*)p1;
    char* second = (char*)p2;
    return first[0] - second[0];
}

int pred_str(const void* p1, const void* p2) {
    const char** first = ((const char**)p1);
    const char** second = ((const char**)p2);
    return strcmp(first[0], second[0]);
}
```

And this is how I use the function for int vectors and sets:

```
int nInt = sizeof(arr_int) / sizeof(*arr_int);
std::vector<int> vec_int(arr_int, arr_int + nInt);
std::vector<int>::iterator maxintVec = find_max(vec_int.begin(),
        vec_int.end(), pred_int);

std::set<int> set_int(arr_int, arr_int + nInt);
    std::set<int>::iterator maxintSet = find_max(set_int.begin(),
        set_int.end(), pred_int);
```

I'm open to any suggestions as to how to change this code so it could work for all given data structures. Thank you!

Comment: Container iterators are not pointers, and they cannot be converted to a `void *`. So the answer seems to be "bad predicate design".

Comment: @F. Kukec By the way sets are already sorted containers.

Comment: First write your predicates the way you would for the STL containers, and *then* try writing an algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

C++ already has a standard [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) algorithm that does EXACTLY what you are attempting to implement manually, eg:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

int arr_int[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 9, 2, 0 };
int main(){
  int* maxint = std::max_element(&arr_int[0], &arr_int[sizeof(arr_int)/sizeof(*arr_int)], pred_int);
  // auto maxint = std::max_element(std::begin(arr_int), std::end(arr_int), pred_int);
  std::cout << *maxint <<"\n";
}
```

That being said, the problem is indeed with how you are using the predicates.  Sure, in your `int[]` array example, you are using raw pointers for iterators, so casting the pinters to `void*` and then back to `int*` works.  But, standard container iterators are not implemented using raw pointers, so your casts will not work for them.  Instead, your predicate parameters need to be the actual *value types* that are being compared, not the iterators themselves.  Make the predicates take the container's `value_type` (`int`, `char`, `char*`, etc) and then have `find_max()` dereference the iterators when calling the predicate, eg:

```cpp
template <typename Iterator, typename Predicate>
Iterator find_max(Iterator cur, Iterator last, Predicate pred) {
    Iterator max = cur;
    while (cur != last) {
        if (pred(*max, *cur) < 0) max = cur;
        ++cur;
    }
    return max;
}

int pred_int(int p1, int p2) {
    return p1 - p2;
}

int pred_char(char p1, char p2) {
    return static_cast<int>(p1) - static_cast<int>(p2);
}

int pred_str(char* p1, char* p2) {
    return strcmp(p1, p2);
}

...

int arr_int[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 9, 2, 0 };
int nInt = sizeof(arr_int) / sizeof(*arr_int);

int main(){
  int* maxint = find_max(arr_int, arr_int + nInt, pred_int);
  std::cout << *maxint << "\n";

  std::vector<int> vec_int(arr_int, arr_int + nInt);
  std::vector<int>::iterator maxintVec = find_max(vec_int.begin(), vec_int.end(), pred_int);
  std::cout << *maxintVec << "\n";

  std::set<int> set_int(arr_int, arr_int + nInt);
  std::set<int>::iterator maxintSet = find_max(set_int.begin(), set_int.end(), pred_int);
  std::cout << *maxintSet << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```